# SVProgressHUD is not displaying ring animation

Tags: xcode5, sprite-kit

I am new to Sprite Kit and Programming as a whole. I am successfully making a video game for the iPhone but I just cannot understand how to display an animating ring correctly. I want my future gamers to be able to know that something is going on when the application is loading and Not think that its just frozen.

I want to make a few things clear. Yes I did download SVProgressHUD. I have both the .h and .m file added on my Xcode project. I also did  #import "SVProgressHUD.h" where I need to.

As a matter of fact, part of the code is working excellently because my MaskType Gradient is successfully showing up as it loads. However the animating ring does NOT appear whatsoever.

Is there anything else I have to do to make my ring appear and moving?

Here is my touchesBegan Method Code in where I am using the Progress Indicator:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event


{


SKSpriteNode *DECO = (SKSpriteNode*)[self childNodeWithName:@"DECO"];



DECO.name = @"DECO";
UITouch*touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:location];
if  ([node.name isEqualToString:@"DECO"])


{
    [SVProgressHUD showWithMaskType:SVProgressHUDMaskTypeGradient];


    SKAction *fadeAway = [SKAction fadeOutWithDuration:1.0];

    [DECO runAction:fadeAway completion:^{
        SKScene *cloudScene = [[CloudScene alloc]initWithSize:self.size];

        SKTransition *doors =
        [SKTransition doorwayWithDuration:1.0];


        [self.view presentScene:cloudScene transition:doors];
        [SVProgressHUD dismiss];


        }
     ];

}
```

Comment: Did you check if condition `[node.name isEqualToString:@"DECO"]` is met? Setting a breakpoint just after that line would help

Comment: @Andrey I don't think that is the problem. I just did as you said and everything is fine. I have even changed my "[SVProgressHUD showWithMaskType:SVProgressHUDMaskTypeGradient];" method call to "[SVProgressHUD showProgress:1];" and the ring Actually Displays clearly. However, it doesn't move at all ! it is just a picture. There has to be a line of code for making it animated. I have to be missing something, or putting something in the wrong place.